# Truncating a TimelinePlot?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I have a very large [TimelinePlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimelinePlot.html) dataset that extends months out into the future (it is being used as a milestone timeline, similar to a Gantt chart).

**Question:** Is there a way to programatically truncate the dataset (say from now until 4 weeks from now), so that I can zoomed in snapshot of what is immediately in view (over the coming weeks)?

Comment: Have you tried just using `PlotRange` on your larger plot? Otherwise, without example data, it's a little hard to answer.